# Xcode DispatchQueue.main.async inside or outside large loop?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

i am trying to edit/Insert CoreData objects , what i am doing is this :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  for track in allTracks
  {
    if let i = allObjects.index(where: { $0.sid == ddTools().md5("\(track.song_name)\(track.artist_name)") } )
    {
      self.log("[NEW][\(i)] Already in DB : \(track.song_name)")
    }else
    {
      self.insert_track(track)
    }
  }
}
```

but its still blocking the UI if Array has over 500+ object , is it safe if i do this ?

```
  for track in allTracks
  {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let i = allObjects.index(where: { $0.sid == ddTools().md5("\(track.song_name)\(track.artist_name)") } )
        {
          self.log("[NEW][\(i)] Already in DB : \(track.song_name)")
        }else
        {
          self.insert_track(track)
        }
    }
  }
```

can i use DispatchQueue.main.async inside looping of CoreData objects ! to void blocking UI

> after some advices i have updated the function to this

```
func insert_or_update_songs(tracks:[DTO_SONG],onComplete:(()->())!)
{

    let allTasksGroup     = DispatchGroup()
    var totalFinished:Int = 0


    for track in tracks
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
          allTasksGroup.enter()

            //Fetch if Exists
          let context             = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
          let songHash            = ddTools().md5("\(track.song_name)\(track.artist_name)")
          let request             = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Song_Entity")
              request.predicate   = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [NSPredicate(format:"sid = %@", songHash),
                                                                                        NSPredicate(format:"sid != %@", "")])

          do{

                  if  try context.count(for:request) > 0
                  {
                     //Update the Track
                     if let _tracks:[Song_Entity] = try context.fetch(request) as? [Song_Entity]
                     {
                        self.update_track(track, _tracks[0])
                     }

                  }else
                  //Insert as new track
                  {
                    self.insert_track(track,context :context)
                  }

                if context.hasChanges
                {
                   do {
                          try context.save()
                          self.log(" New Changes has been Saved.")
                       } catch let error as NSError {   self.log(" Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)") }
                }

                totalFinished += 1
                print(" \(totalFinished)/\(tracks.count)")
                allTasksGroup.leave()

             }catch let error as NSError {  self.log("[HASH] Error while checking Track if in DB: \(error), \(error.userInfo)") }

        }
    }

    //When all done
    allTasksGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        self.log("[INSERT OR UPDATE BATCH] Total Finished : \(totalFinished)/\(tracks.count) ")

        if totalFinished == tracks.count
        {
           if onComplete != nil
           {
              onComplete()
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For both CoreData tread safety and responsiveness of your UI, I'd go with doing the thread switch at the `insert` point:

```
for track in allTracks
{
    if let i = allObjects.index(where: { $0.sid == ddTools().md5("\(track.song_name)\(track.artist_name)") } ) {
      self.log("[NEW][\(i)] Already in DB : \(track.song_name)")
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.insert_track(track)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: self.insert_track already in  DispatchQueue.main.async form inside

Comment: Yes but this one gets the item out of CoreData in the right thread and then uses in the main thread.

Comment: and should i use context.save after the loop ? or inside each loop

Comment: Where are you writing to Core Data?

Comment: i have updated the question and the function after ur advice , with coredata

Answer (score 0):

Both snippets of code are wrong.  `allTracks` are core-data objects that are attached to a particular context - which is not thread safe.  You cannot access these objects - neither reading or writing - from the main thread.  You can save the information - and then pass that to the main thread.

If you doing the fetch to use on the main thread, you shouldn't be using a background thread in the first place.  It is better to just do the fetch on the main thread.

Comment: allTracks is not coredata objects , allObjects is . so u mean i have to loop allTracks and inside the loop make coredata fetch and save for each track ?

Comment: then you cannot access allObjects on the main thread. but it is the same idea.  I don't see anywhere in your code that you are writing to core data.

Comment: i have updated the question and the function after ur advice , with coredata